# AngularJS ng-init $broadcast called before listeners registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to broadcast initial values to an indeterminate number of listeners with $broadcast

I am calling $rootScope.$broadcast with ng-init. The broadcast works correctly on page load but the listeners are not registered. Subsequent calls are picked up correctly, however.

The html;

`<div class="panel panel-body" ng-controller="Location" ng-init="setActiveLocation({{ defaultLocation }})">`

The method;

```
    $scope.setActiveLocation = function(location) {
        console.log('broadcast:', location);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('setActiveLocation', location);
    };
```

A listener;

```
       $scope.$on('setActiveLocation', function(event, location)
            {
                console.log('recieved: ', event)
                $scope.clearHistory();
                $scope.refreshHistory(location);
            });
```

My question is this; ng-init should be called when the page is ready, so why is it called prior to listeners being ready? What should I do to prevent this?

Comment: You should consider moving the call to setActiveLocation to the controller. Putting it in ng-init is putting part of the logic inside html with few benefits. The [documentation for ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) says: "This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. ..."

Comment: it is in the controller.... check the html again, unless I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I was just refering to: ng-init="setActiveLocation({{ defaultLocation }})". If you have the call to setActiveLocation inside the controller you can make sure listeners have been setup before.

BTW: it should probably be setActiveLocation(defaultLocation) not setActiveLocation({{defaultLocation}}), if you want to keep it inside ng-init.

Comment: I should add that {{defaultLocation}} is an object passed via twig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ng-init should be called when the page is ready". This assumption is wrong. Look at the ngInitDirective (currently angular 1.4.7).

```
var ngInitDirective = ngDirective({
  priority: 450,
  compile: function() {
    return {
      pre: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$eval(attrs.ngInit);
      }
    };
  }
});
```

It is executed during the `pre-link` phase and has othing to do with the state of state of the page.

So i guess your set up is like this:

```
<a ng-init="someFunctionInA()">
    <b ng-init="someFunctionInB()"></b>
</a>
```

If the controller attached to `a` does the `$broadcast` and the listener is registered in the controller attached to `b`, then your broadcast is fired before the listener is even registered.

**Solution:**
Do not use `ng-init`. Call the init function from your directive. Make the call of your broadcast function from the `post-link` function of directive `a`. While `pre-link` gets executed from outer to inner directive, post-link does vice-versa and so your inner controllers (with the listeners) will be ready before the outer ones do the broadcast.